# Spring Cloud Config Server lookup through Eureka using Java instead of bootstrap.yml

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I'm attempting to build code into our base pom which autoconfigures Spring Cloud Config server lookup through Eureka.  We're doing this to avoid templating .yml properties for developers building microservices.  For example, we want to java config all behavior triggered from these properties:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: MyMicroservice
  cloud:
    config:
      enabled: true
    server:
      prefix: /diagnostics/admin/config
    failFast: true
    discovery:
      enabled: true
      serviceId: echo

management:
  context-path: /diagnostics/admin

eureka:
  password: password
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://user:${eureka.password}@localhost:8761/eureka/
  instance:
    leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 10
    statusPageUrlPath: /diagnostics/admin/info
    healthCheckUrlPath: /diagnostics/admin/health
```

After much experimenting, the following approach mostly works except for the Eureka-discovered config server (resulting in no overridden config properties):

```
@Order(-1)
public class AdditionalBootstrapPropertySourceLocator implements PropertySourceLocator {

    @Override
    public PropertySource<?> locate(Environment environment) {
        Map<String, Object> theBootstrapYmlConfig = new HashMap<>();
        theBootstrapYmlConfig.put("spring.cloud.config.enabled", new Boolean(true));
        theBootstrapYmlConfig.put("spring.cloud.config.server.prefix", "/diagnostics/admin/config");
        theBootstrapYmlConfig.put("spring.cloud.config.failFast", new Boolean(true));
        theBootstrapYmlConfig.put("spring.cloud.config.discovery.enabled", new Boolean(true));
        theBootstrapYmlConfig.put("spring.cloud.config.discovery.serviceId", "echo");

        theBootstrapYmlConfig.put("management.context-path", "/diagnostics/admin");

        theBootstrapYmlConfig.put("eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone", "http://user:password@localhost:8761/eureka/");
        theBootstrapYmlConfig.put("eureka.instance.leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds", new Integer(10));
        theBootstrapYmlConfig.put("eureka.instance.statusPageUrlPath", "/diagnostics/admin/info");
        theBootstrapYmlConfig.put("eureka.instance.healthCheckUrlPath", "/diagnostics/admin/health");

        return new MapPropertySource("myExtraBootstrap", theBootstrapYmlConfig);    
    }    
}
```

And I seem to need this Bean as well:

```
@ConditionalOnWebApplication
@Configuration
@Import(EurekaClientAutoConfiguration.class)
public class WorkfrontDiscoveryClientConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnClass({ DiscoveryClient.class, ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.class })
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    DiscoveryClientConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration discoveryClientConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration() {
        DiscoveryClientConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration discoveryClientConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration =
                 new DiscoveryClientConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration();
        return discoveryClientConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration;
    }

}
```

Finally, I put both into spring.factories to ensure they are constructed.  The problem is that the PropertySourceLocator is never used to construct the call within ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator to retrieve the properties.  No matter what I do, I cant seem to match the behaviors that specifying the properties within bootstrap.yml would produce.

**Edit 4 days later**

The key factor (and restriction) here is the ability to look up the config server through Eureka.  In the current spring cloud release (1.0.2), the property source is retrieved and constructed too early in the spring initialization cycle for the config-lookup-through-eureka java property source config I have above.  Plus if the Eureka server is slow or not available at bootstrap startup time, the Config server property source is never reconstructed when Eureka finally comes up.  This in my mind is a bug.

I solved this all by eliminating the concept of looking up the config server through Eureka, and requiring this minimum config in bootstrap.yml:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: MyMicroservice
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://localhost:8888/diagnostics/admin/config

eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://user:password@localhost:8761/eureka/
```

and then setting the rest in the java AdditionalBootstrapPropertySourceLocator

**Edit 30 days later**

Java-configing bootstrap properties continues to be a challenge.  I'm doing this because I'm developing a framework without templating or code generation (the premise of spring boot).   I've added spring-retry to the mix and client-to-config gets retried but re-registration to Eureka does not.  This is why Eureka-first had to be abandoned for me.  I'd put my vote in for integrating spring-retry into the Eureka registration process so I can go back to Eureka-first for my framework.  Still on Spring Cloud 1.0.2.

**Edit 100 days later**

Update for where we ended up.  Continuing along our mantra of avoiding property templating, enforcing policies and practices within code .. and continuing without a Eureka-first concept, we abandoned PropertySourceLocator and simply used a SpringApplicationRunListener as follows:

```
public class OurFrameworkProperties implements SpringApplicationRunListener {
  :
  public void started() {
    if (TestCaseUtils.isRunningFromTestCase()) {
      System.setProperty("spring.cloud.config.failFast", "false");
      System.setProperty("spring.cloud.config.enabled", "false");
      System.setProperty("eureka.client.enabled", "false");
    } else {
      // set production values same way
    }
  }
}
```

A caution that this started() actually gets called twice inside the spring code (once not passing any program arguments btw) everytime your Spring application runs or gets an Actuator refresh().

Comment: Is it possible you could just add a `@PropertySource`? All that manual schlepping of map keys looks fragile to me anway.

Comment: The point was to java config this automatically for developers who specify our base pom as their pom's parent.  We didn't want to rely on tribal knowledge for developers to remember to add a file called 'bootstrap.yml' or any other file to their classpath or working directory.  This way they'd be registered automatically with Eureka, get our standardized config overrides from the config server automatically, and share a common management context path.   The code was templated from _http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/spring-cloud.html#customizing-bootstrap-property-sources_ .

Comment: After investigation, there seems to be a bug.  Updates Eureka provides as to the Config server URI does not trigger the restTemplate call to resolve the remote property source within `ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.locate()`.  If I go back to configuring using bootstrap.yml (and remove failFast), if Eureka is not immediately available by the time context init finished  -> the config server property source overrides are never created

Comment: Eureka might not be available I get that. Does it work when you /refresh in that case?

Comment: BTW you don't have to rely on tribal knowledge to include a                             properties file - that's the point of using `@ProeprtySource`.

Comment: After everything starts, calling /refresh on the service does properly bind the config server overrides.   Then I tried registering a SpringApplicationRunListener and call context.refresh within finished() but that didn't work since then there were nested context refreshes going on and calling it twice threw exceptions.   What I thought I was doing with this java config was another alternative to @PropertySource files.  I ended up giving up the Eureka-first concept (config retrieved through discovery) and merely configured the endpoints in .yml file.  Then things worked  I'll update when done.

Answer (score 0):

If your `PropertySourceLocator` is listed in`spring.factories` (I assume as a `BootstrapConfiguration`) then it needs to be a `@Component` (or maybe even a `@Configuration`).

Comment: That still doesn't solve it.  Two problems:  1) In PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.initialize() it seems like it is intended to load the PropertySources into the composite.  My Property Source is added to the composite properly.  However, ConfigServicePropertySourceLocation is also part of the initialization loop.  That acts likes its going to use the environment to override its defaults, but only does for 3 properties (wouldn’t matter anyway since my PropertySource was not yet merged into the environment property sources).

Comment: 2) I notice also that my DiscoveryClientConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration bean is also not being created early enough in the process for all this to work.  I’m at wits end figuring out how to instantiate that bean equal in order to the AdditionalBootstrapPropertySourceLocator.  Any ideas?

Comment: `DiscoveryClientConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration` is already a `BootstrapConfiguration`. Why do you want to add another?

Comment: It has `@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "spring.cloud.config.discovery.enabled", matchIfMissing = false)` and therefore does not trigger during bootstrap time (comes up in the Negative matches: list). It does not pick up `theBootstrapYmlConfig.put("spring.cloud.config.discovery.enabled", new Boolean(true));` at that point. When I compare and start with bootstrap.yml populated, DiscoveryClientConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration is constructed at bootstrap time and shows up in the "Positive matches" list. Debugging has me concluding that this bean constructed early must be the key.

Comment: OK,.. It does need DiscoveryClientConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration early, but doing that got crazy with other dependencies it needed for Eureka.  Unless its really early, any updates Eureka provides as to the Config server URI (initiated only by ContextRefreshedEvent & HeartbeatEvent and placed into ConfigClientProperties) does not trigger the restTemplate call you make to resolve the remote property source within ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.locate().  Same problem if Eureka is not immediately available by the time context init finished  -> config server property source never created

Answer (score 0):

you have to set this properties in the boostrap.properties

```
eureka.instance.metadataMap.configPath: /your-app-name
```

and comment this one

```
#spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8888/
```

and obviously it must be also this

```
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone: ${EUREKA_URI:http://localhost:8761/eureka}
eureka.client.instance.preferIpAddress: true
```

according with the documentation
https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_client.html#discovery-first-bootstrap